# Ejb3 dependency in Maven

Tags: java, maven-2, ejb-3.0

I saw recently that Sun/a third party had released a maven dependency containing only the interfaces for e.g. EJB3 and JPA.

Does anyone know the groupId, artifactId, repository etc where they are? 
I would prefer to not use the OpenEJB, Glassfish counterparts etc.

Answer (score 18):

If you want the latest Java EE 6 (EJB 3.1, JPA 2.0, etc) Then you can use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

and it's also in the java.net repository:

```
<repository>
    <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
    <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
    <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

Comment: +1 for the support of EJB 3.1 and newer. ejb-api dependency provided with other answers support only up to verson 3.0.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that layout of the repository "maven2-repository.dev.java.net" has changed.
At the moment correct dependency is as below:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
  <artifactId>ejb-api</artifactId>
  <version>3.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I just followed this and worked for me. The only think I changed was the scope from "test" to "provided". Don't know how but it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

There is those dependecies :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

provided by java.net repository :

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
        <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <layout>default</layout>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

---

**Resources :**

- [Maven - Coping with Sun JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-coping-with-sun-jars.html)